# Exam with 18pt main font

Tags: fontsize, exam, accessibility

I've written an exam paper for my students, using the [`exam`](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/#ExamCls) class with fairly standard options, and specifically using the `12pt` class option for 12 point type. I've just been informed that a student has vision problems that require an 18pt main font. What is a good way to achieve this? Some things that might be of impact:

1. I don't make much use of smaller fonts (e.g., `\small`, etc.) but redefining just `normalsize` would not be sufficient since question
   headings, etc., use a larger size (mostly `\large`).
2. Probably the cover page could remain the original size - it's the
   main question text that really matters
3. Something a bit more that 18pt would be fine
4. I do not want to switch classes, as my existing source depends upon
   the `exam` class
5. I have been asked to keep to the original A4 page size, rather than scaling
   everything up to a larger page, because exam desks have limited
   size.

Comment: print on larger papers?

Comment: @davyjones Our exams office asks that we keep to A4 to make the pages manageable on a standard exam desk (not very large)

Comment: The [`exam-n`](https://nxg.me.uk/dist/exam-n/) package has the option `largefont` for font size of `18pt`. You can consider get familiar with this other package if useful.

Comment: @Cragfelt Useful to know of another exam package. Do you know how compatible it is with the `exam` class? I don't have much time to port things across.

Comment: @beldaz Unfortunately I am not familiar with this package. In another hand, you commented the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378301/increase-font-size-of-entire-document-in-documentclassexam to increase font sizes to the entire document using `extarticle`. In the answer of the question
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292655/how-do-i-get-the-font-sizes-i-need-when-they-are-in-between-the-defaults-sae-cl/295530#295530 there is an example of implementation in another context

Comment: In your work, you may put `\documentclass[a4paper,18pt]{extarticle}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd simply add `\usepackage[20pt]{extsizes}`:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[20pt]{extsizes}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
 \question First Question
 \question Second Question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `extsizes` commented out:

[image]

As for the title page, lack of an example makes it difficult to give advice.

Comment: This is the solution I'd have chosen if I'd known it in advance.

Comment: In the documentation, it says: `The sizes available are 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, and 20pt.`. Is there any way to have some size in-between or larger (e.g. `16pt`)?

Comment: @Diaa You should create your own `.clo` file based on the others. You find them in the same directory as `extsizes.sty`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to do so. Could you please refer to me to any relevant question?

Comment: @Diaa Look at `size17.clo` and `size20.clo`, mediating over them to create a `size18.clo` file.

Answer (score 4):

With `extarticle` from [extsizes](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) you can increase the font size up to `20pt` in the entire document. To load the font options from this class to the `exam` class you can create a customized document class, lets say, `myexam`.

You need to create a `.cls` document in your editor with the following code

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myexam}[YYYY/MM/DD My exam class] %Current date

%%Preliminary definitions, needed by the options
\LoadClass[a4paper,18pt]{extarticle}

%%This parts handles the options passed to the class.
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%%Body of the class, most of the declarations appear here (if necessary).
%
```

Once you have created it, you can call as usual at the top of your preamble with

```
\documentclass{myexam}
```

**P.S.:** You can consult the following questions for further information

1. [Difference between \LoadClass and \LoadClassWithOptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/difference-between-loadclass-and-loadclasswithoptions)
2. [How to set default font size in latex cls file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40893/how-to-set-default-font-size-in-latex-cls-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Also there is other package for exams named [`exam-n`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam-n) package, that has the option `largefont` for font size of  `18pt`. You can consider get familiar with this other package if useful for you.

Comment: To use the `exam` class I have the first line `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}` so presumably there's no way to have two document classes simultaneously. Is there a simple way around this? In your other comment you link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292655/how-do-i-get-the-font-sizes-i-need-when-they-are-in-between-the-defaults-sae-cl/295530#295530 that seems to change the base class to use `extarticle` but that seems to require hacking up a class file that is used by other documents.

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: trying out the different options to see what works best. Will select answer once that's clear.

Answer (score 3):

I tested the recommendation of [that comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt#comment379197_30699) to use `scrextend` package, and it works for me better than `extsizes` since I don't have to choose from a limited number of font sizes.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize=18pt]{scrextend}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question First Question
        \question Second Question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are cleaner, but for posterity I'm posting the hackier solution we implemented in the limited time we had.

We used the `\fontsize` command (see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4140/60034) to change the font size to 18pt (with 22pt baselineskip) after the cover page content, using:

```
\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\selectfont
```

It actually took a fair bit of work to tidy things up afterwards (oversize tables and paragraphs needing manual line breaks, adjusted page breaks, etc.) that required us to make a copy of the entire exam script source and edit it specially. So while the the source was rather neatly implemented as multiple files (one per question) `\input`ted from a top-level document this special version did not lend itself to a single-line solution.