# exam/extsizes: How to create a new <size*>.clo file for unavailable font-size?

Tags: fontsize, exam, extsizes

Following up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402049/2288), how can I create a font size that `extsizes` doesn't have?

In other words, what should be done to create, for example, `size12.clo` out of the existing [size9.clo](https://pastebin.com/u11KnBJi) and [size14.clo](https://pastebin.com/i0PmwhzU)? Or how to create `size32.clo` out of [size20.clo](https://pastebin.com/yGpQEMJ9)?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[20pt]{extsizes}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
 \question First Question
 \question Second Question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [that comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt#comment379197_30699), the versatile package `scrextend` can easily get the job done.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize=32pt]{scrextend}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question First Question
        \question Second Question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```